# How do I add SSR OSI to SABRE 2.2.1 API

Tags: sabre, sabredav

Below is sample request I made, and below is the response I'm getting.
If you can post sample SpecialServiceRq OSI entry request and response sample that would help a lot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SpecialServiceRQ ReturnHostCommand="false" TimeStamp="2018-03-05T19:02:32.219-05:00" Version="2.2.1" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:ns2="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01">
    <SpecialServiceInfo>
        <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A">
            <PersonName DateOfBirth="1969-02-25" Gender="M" NameNumber="1.1">
                <GivenName>LIAM</GivenName>
                <Surname>JACKSON</Surname>
            </PersonName>
        </SecureFlight>
        <Service SSR_Code="OSI">
            <Text>CTCE/ACCEPT//TEST.CORP.COMPANY.COM</Text>
        </Service>
    </SpecialServiceInfo>
</SpecialServiceRQ>]

[03-05-18 19:02:32.462] [SplitAgentBooker_10009498321_10009498321_2139481603] INFO   SABREpl_timings - : T:0.234 secs S:ABE_ABEBOOKD01_9RVB_000000000002 A:SpecialServiceLLSRS M:2139481603_37114603_37772403_14 RSP: [<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SpecialServiceRS Version="2.2.1" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
        <stl:Error timeStamp="2018-03-05T18:02:32-06:00" type="BusinessLogic">
            <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                <stl:Message>.CHECK ENTRY FORMAT.NOT ENT BGNG WITH</stl:Message>
                <stl:Message>3OSI  CTCE/ACCEPT//TEST.CORP.COMPANY.COM</stl:Message>
                <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
            </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
        </stl:Error>
    </stl:ApplicationResults>
</SpecialServiceRS>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to create the 3CTCEA/ACCEPT//TEST.CORP.COMPANY.COM-1.1 format, then you don't have to use the SecureFlight node, as that one creates the 3DOCS format.

I would advise to remove it altogether:

```
<SpecialServiceRQ TimeStamp="2018-03-05T19:02:32.219-05:00" Version="2.2.1" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:ns2="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" ReturnHostCommand="true">
<SpecialServiceInfo>
    <Service SSR_Code="CTCE" SegmentNumber="A">
        <PersonName NameNumber="1.1"/>
        <Text>ACCEPT//TEST.CORP.COMPANY.COM</Text>
    </Service>
</SpecialServiceInfo>
```

This way you will create the above format. If this is not the format let me know which one is and I will help with that one as well.